# Does heroku postgres support reactive?

Tags: heroku-postgres

Can an application built using quarkus with reactive be deployed on heroku? As far as I could see, for heroku postgre, only jdbc is mentioned in the heroku documentation.

Quarkus reactive uses mutiny.

https://quarkus.io/blog/mutiny-vertx/
https://vertx.io/docs/